# domain redirection in htaccess file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect my domain landing page to other domain but I don't want to Redirect Everything After the Domain landing page.Can any one help me How I can do this. my htaccess file :-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^women\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.women\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/beta\.women\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

I want *women.com* landing page redirect to *beta.women.com* **but** women.com?post_type=in_product&p=509&preview=1 or women.com/about or everything after women.com/ **not to redirect to** beta.women.com

any help will be highly appreciated !

Thank you !

Comment: `everything after women.com/ not to redirect to beta.women.com` Then what should be redirected?

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for reply. only redirect women.com I mean home page only.

Comment: So you want only want to redirect landing page of `women.com` to beta.women.com`?

Comment: @anubhava Yes.....only landing page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep redirect rule before other rules and exclude any query string from redirect using a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(women\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://beta.%1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I don't want to to write anything like post_type in htaccess file.

Comment: I want this bcoz I don't know exact query and can you do this in my file...